# Bootstrap show/hide tab component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've run into an issue using Bootstrap's tab component. I'm trying to figure out how to, on click of a specific tab, hide a lorem ipsum section and show a hidden div and then, on click/selection of a different tab, hide the hidden div again and show the lorem ipsum section again.

```js
$(function(){
    
     $('.nav-tabs a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });  
     
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#one" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#three" data-toggle="tab">Three</a></li> 
</ul>

<div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="one">               
        <p>One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="two">                    
        <p>Two</p>
    </div>            
    <div class="tab-pane" id="three">                    
        <p>On click of this tab hide lorem ipsum and show content</p>
    </div>            
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">    
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas auctor placerat ex a posuere. Integer feugiat, orci ac vestibulum rhoncus, arcu tellus volutpat ante, in accumsan diam nisl vitae tellus. In at eros sit amet quam luctus auctor. Donec a gravida nisl, nec aliquam lectus. Sed mattis bibendum elementum. Nullam cursus scelerisque arcu, a eleifend sapien posuere nec. Nunc ut fringilla erat. Aenean egestas felis tortor, vel bibendum ligula elementum nec. Etiam ultricies blandit arcu vel cursus. Vestibulum at felis libero. Nulla nec lectus purus. Aliquam tempor rutrum sagittis.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">    
    <div class="hidden">
        <!-- On click of the third tab hide lorem ipsum and show this div & if another tab is selected hide this again and show lorem ipsum -->    
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zacnespral21/fkv5tvaz/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try looking in this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs if you have not already. Couldn't understand your question properly? Do you mean you want to change `hidden` property of `div` or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your js code should look like this:

```
$('.nav-pills a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).attr('href')=='#three'){
        $('#lorem-text').hide();
        $('#hidden-text div').removeClass('hidden')
    }
    else{
        $('#lorem-text').show();
        $('#hidden-text div').addClass('hidden')
    }
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    
     $('.nav-tabs a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if($(this).attr('href')=='#three'){
            $('#lorem-text').hide();
            $('#hidden-text div').show()
        }
        else{
         $('#lorem-text').show();
            $('#hidden-text div').hide()
        }
        $(this).tab('show');
    });  
     
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#one" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#three" data-toggle="tab">Three</a></li> 
</ul>

<div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="one">               
        <p>One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="two">                    
        <p>Two</p>
    </div>            
    <div class="tab-pane" id="three">                    
        <p>On click of this tab hide lorem ipsum and show content</p>
    </div>            
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" id="lorem-text">    
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas auctor placerat ex a posuere. Integer feugiat, orci ac vestibulum rhoncus, arcu tellus volutpat ante, in accumsan diam nisl vitae tellus. In at eros sit amet quam luctus auctor. Donec a gravida nisl, nec aliquam lectus. Sed mattis bibendum elementum. Nullam cursus scelerisque arcu, a eleifend sapien posuere nec. Nunc ut fringilla erat. Aenean egestas felis tortor, vel bibendum ligula elementum nec. Etiam ultricies blandit arcu vel cursus. Vestibulum at felis libero. Nulla nec lectus purus. Aliquam tempor rutrum sagittis.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12" id="hidden-text">    
    <div class="hidden">
        <!-- On click of the third tab hide lorem ipsum and show this div & if another tab is selected hide this again and show lorem ipsum -->    
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Tom, much appreciated. However I'd prefer to use the bootstrap events that @xdhmoore suggested.

Comment: @ZacNespral21: Sure, I agree, is more elegant :) +1 for both

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using [events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events)

```js
$(function(){
    
     $('.nav-tabs a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

    //Added a class for the tab control, but there's a better name
    $('.tab-control-three').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

        //Change this class from bootstrap's 'hidden' 
        //to something that doesn't force display:none
        $('.hidden-text').show();

        //You'll need to add a class for this, 
        //but please name it something better :P
        $('.lorem-ipsum').hide();

    })  
     
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#one" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>    
    <li><a class="tab-control-three" href="#three" data-toggle="tab">Three</a></li> 
</ul>

<div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="one">               
        <p>One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="two">                    
        <p>Two</p>
    </div>            
    <div class="tab-pane" id="three">                    
        <p>On click of this tab hide lorem ipsum and show content</p>
    </div>            
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">    
    <div>
        <p class="lorem-ipsum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas auctor placerat ex a posuere. Integer feugiat, orci ac vestibulum rhoncus, arcu tellus volutpat ante, in accumsan diam nisl vitae tellus. In at eros sit amet quam luctus auctor. Donec a gravida nisl, nec aliquam lectus. Sed mattis bibendum elementum. Nullam cursus scelerisque arcu, a eleifend sapien posuere nec. Nunc ut fringilla erat. Aenean egestas felis tortor, vel bibendum ligula elementum nec. Etiam ultricies blandit arcu vel cursus. Vestibulum at felis libero. Nulla nec lectus purus. Aliquam tempor rutrum sagittis.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">    
    <div class="hidden-text">
        <!-- On click of the third tab hide lorem ipsum and show this div & if another tab is selected hide this again and show lorem ipsum -->    
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The toggle back for other tabs should be similar.

Comment: This is not going to work, since the `hidden` bootstrap class has `display:none!important;` and there is no element with `id="three"`

Comment: This is perfect, I didn't even think to check the bootstrap events. Thanks!

Comment: @Tom Sarduy Good catch.  Editing.

Comment: The 'three' is the 3rd tab. No?

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. I'm selecting the tab panes instead of the tab controls. Idk if this will work.  Editing again.

Comment: @xdhmoore Looks like i jumped the gun on thinking the bootstrap events would work. What im looking for is this http://jsfiddle.net/zacnespral21/fkv5tvaz/
Tom's code is the way i had to do it, since the bootstrap events wont do what i want. Thanks for the help though, I can actually use this for something else im working on :)

Comment: Lol, just kidding.  Good luck! :)